# How to properly convert multiple database records to json via php

Tags: php

I have json record which was build manually below which work fine with my application

```
<?php 

$arr= '{
"items": [{
        "title": "my first title",
        "id": "101",
        "address": {
            "label": "my first label",
            "countryCode": "FRA"
        },
        "position": {
            "lat": 37.37634,
            "lng": -122.03405
        }
    },

    {
        "title": "my second title",
        "id": "102",
        "address": {
            "label": "my second label",
            "countryCode": "USA"
        },
        "position": {
            "lat": 37.37634,
            "lng": -122.03405
        }
    }
]
}';

echo $arr;    
?>
```

**Here is my issue:**   I have a database  with records below which I want to covert to Json as per format above. my main issue is how to implement the **address{}** and **position{}** parameters in the json records.

Here is my efforts so far

```
include('pdo.php');

$res1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM data");
$res1->execute(array());


while($row = $res1->fetch()){

    $id = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $label = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['label'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $title = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $countryCode = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['countryCode'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $lat = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['lat'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $lng = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['lng'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    
    
    $arr[] = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "label" => $label,
            "title" => $title,
            "countryCode" => $countryCode,
            "lat" => $lat,
            "lng" => $lng
        );
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an array or an object if you prefer and place in them what belongs, then place that in the array you have

```
while($row = $res1->fetch()){

    $title = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['title'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $id = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    
    $addr = [];
    $addr['label']        = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['label'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $addr['countryCode']  = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['countryCode'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

    $pos = [];
    $pos['lat'] = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['lat'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $pos['lng'] = htmlentities(htmlentities($row['lng'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

    $arr[] = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "title" => $title,
            "address" => $addr,
            "position" => $pos
        );
}
echo json_encode(["items"=>$arr]);
```

Answer (score 1):

address{} and position{} should be arrays:

```
$arr[] = array(
    "id" => $id,    
    "title" => $title,    
    "address" => [
        "label" => $label,
        "countryCode" => $countryCode,
    ],
    "position" => [
        "lat" => $lat,
        "lng" => $lng,
    ],
);
```